How to truly exclude paths from code navigation in VSCode
It happens often that I "Ctrl + click" on a symbol and VSCode takes me to some cache in my home directory /home/<user>/.cache/. The same file often exists in my workspace but still the cache version gets pulled up.
How can I avoid this from happening? The cache directory is totally outside of VSCode's workspace, so I am very confused as to how it is even finding it :(
